# Managing multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an onboarding DataFrame with clients: ID, name and age. 
For each client, I have another DataFrame with his performance details.

I'm not sure how to link these dataframes, to easily find performance details for a specific client.

I understand the easiest way would be having only 2 DataFrames: clients and performance; and apply the necessary filters. BUT that's not the solution I want.

I need one "sub-DataFrame" for each client, to make the calculations I need on the performance DataFrame easier and flexible.

The only solution I could think of is to store the performance DataFrame as a column on the clients DataFrame, so I could access it.

Is there another clean way of doing that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some sample data (a few rows via `df.head().to_dict()` is sufficient), otherwise it's not clear what you mean and hard for responders to demonstrate a solution. Also, read *[mcve]. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID on each dataframe, then you can merge the dataframes using the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function of pandas.

Comment: I don't want to merge anything.